# Saving multiple checkboxes with WordPress settings api

Tags: settings-api

I'm having trouble saving multiple checkboxes using WordPress settings api. I can add multiple values, but only the last checked box gets saved.

This is what I currently have

```
function uwcc_checkbox_field_1_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'uwcc_settings' );
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1]' <?php checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], Mastercard ); ?> value='Mastercard'>
    <label>Mastercard</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1]' <?php checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], Visa ); ?> value='Visa'>
   <label>Visa</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1]' <?php checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], Amex ); ?> value='Amex'>
   <label>Amex</label>
<?php

}
```

I did try placing [] at the end of all of the uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1] like below but then no settings save.

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1][]' <?php checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], Mastercard ); ?> value='Mastercard'>
<label>Mastercard</label>
```

How do I get it to save all fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field name should be `uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1][]`, i.e. turn the field into an array.

Secondly, when saved as an array, you should use `in_array()` along with the [`checked()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) function. But first, let's put the `uwcc_checkbox_field_1` option's values into a variable:

```
$uwcc_checkbox_field_1 = isset( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'] ) ?
  (array) $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'] : [];
```

Now you call `checked()` like so — the `1`, for example in the first line, means the default value (as in `<input value="Mastercard" type="checkbox".../>`) is `Mastercard`:

```
checked( in_array( 'Mastercard', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 )
checked( in_array( 'Visa', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 )
checked( in_array( 'Amex', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 )
```

The full code, tried & tested working: (re-indented for clarity)

```
function uwcc_checkbox_field_1_render() {

    $options = get_option( 'uwcc_settings', [] );

    $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 = isset( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'] )
        ? (array) $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'] : [];
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1][]' <?php checked( in_array( 'Mastercard', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 ); ?> value='Mastercard'>
        <label>Mastercard</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1][]' <?php checked( in_array( 'Visa', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 ); ?> value='Visa'>
       <label>Visa</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='uwcc_settings[uwcc_checkbox_field_1][]' <?php checked( in_array( 'Amex', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 ); ?> value='Amex'>
       <label>Amex</label>
    <?php

}
```

*And don't forget to quote the checkbox values; e.g. `'Mastercard'` and not `Mastercard`.* See below, assuming that the `Mastercard` is not a PHP constant:

```
checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], Mastercard )   // bad
checked( $options['uwcc_checkbox_field_1'], 'Mastercard' ) // good

checked( in_array( Mastercard, $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 )   // bad
checked( in_array( 'Mastercard', $uwcc_checkbox_field_1 ), 1 ) // good
```

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thank you. I added [] to the end of the checkbox_field_1 to allow multiple selects. I'm still learning but having fun at the same time.

Comment: And I still make mistakes sometimes.. sorry about the missing `[]`!

Comment: It's all good Sally CJ. I'm learning all about hide and seek. ';"} I spent 30 minutes last night trying to figure out what I did wrong only to find that I spelt "don't" inside single quotes instead of double, lol

Comment: Yep, that sounds familiar to me, like when I was writing some JS code, I concatenated some strings using `.` and not `+`... :p But just keep on learning, because we all do. :)