# Multiple checkbox doesn't work in wordpress settings api

Tags: options, settings-api, plugin-options

I was creating a checkbox of roles n WordPress. I successfully generated them but the checked function doesn't seem to work.

Also, it is throwing this warning.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'ue_roles_confirm_Administrator'
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
function username_editor_roles_callback() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $option = get_option( 'username_editor_settings' );
    $roles = $wp_roles->roles;

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $roleName = $role['name'];
        $output = sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="username_editor_settings[ue_roles_confirm_%1$s]" value="%1$s" %2$s><label>%1$s</label><br>', 
            $roleName,
            checked(1, $option["ue_roles_confirm_{$roleName}"])
        );
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

I am unable to find why it doesn't work. I read all the questions regarding using an array with settings API but unfortunately, I didn't get what they are doing.

My main idea is to check which field is checked or not. For example, administrator and editor are checked.

Thanks in advance

**NOTE: The values are successfully saved in the database inside the wp_options table.**
**Update: I solved the checkbox part by using this method**

Thanks to this question: [Saving multiple checkboxes with WordPress settings api](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328648/saving-multiple-checkboxes-with-wordpress-settings-api)

```
function username_editor_roles_callback() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $roles = $wp_roles->roles;

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $roleName = $role['name'];
        $output = sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="username_editor_settings[ue_roles_confirm][]" value="%1$s" %2$s><label>%1$s</label><br>', 
            $roleName,
            checked( in_array($roleName, ue_settings_option()["ue_roles_confirm"]), 1, false )
        );
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

**But the warning issue still appears if I uncheck all the boxes.**

**Solved: I solved all the problems. Adding the working function in answer. If there is a better solution I will still accept the answer even the issue is fixed**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I used to solve the problem

```
function username_editor_roles_callback() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $roles = $wp_roles->roles;

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $roleName = $role['name'];
        $output = sprintf('<input type="checkbox" id="ue_roles_checkbox" name="username_editor_settings[ue_roles_confirm][]" value="%1$s" %2$s><label for="ue_roles_checkbox">%1$s</label><br>', 
            $roleName,
            checked( in_array($roleName, (array) ue_settings_option()["ue_roles_confirm"]), 1, false )
        );
        echo $output;
    }
}
```